# Bulk.insert и преобразование финальных данных

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Есть данные вот такого вида:
[image: http://joxi.ru/KAxpx8oHVy88yA]

Когда они попадают в базу они выглядят следующим образом:
[image: http://joxi.ru/L215QxzHwEOO72]

Вопрос: 
Возможно ли эти данные преобразовать до подобного вида в плане структуры:
[image: http://joxi.ru/p27ZKN9ULGxxOm]

Если да - то каким образом?
(таких `insert-ov` естественно не один - и каждый навешивает дополнительные вложенности со своими обьектными структурами - которые и требуется убрать в конечном виде.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов `bulk.insert({...finaleTimeframeData})` скорее всего создаёт один документ даёт ему уникальный _id и всё это находится в нём.. Если `finaleTimeframeData` это массив с объектами, можно попробовать что-то такое сделать..

```js
let m = [{
    _id: "q",
    ticker: "EURUSD",
    close: 1.1,
    vol: 24,
    _date: Date.now()
  },{
    _id: "q1",
    ticker: "EURUSD",
    close: 2.1,
    vol: 14,
    _date: Date.now()
  },{
    _id: "q2",
    ticker: "EURUSD",
    close: 7.1,
    vol: 1,
    _date: Date.now()
  }]

client.connect(async(err) => {
  const db = await client.db("nameDb");
  const bulk = await db.collection('nameCollection').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  for (obj of m) {
    //obj._date = Date.now(); // Если например исправить формат даты надо
    await bulk.insert(obj);
  }
  await bulk.execute();
  client.close();
});
```

Comment: Я так понимаю вы предлагаете загрузить все одним махом в базу?
(я так уже пробовал и мой второй скрин в посте именно с этой реализации)
дело в том что у меня не 3 документа - а 7 000 000 документов как минимум. )
И я пытаюсь делать порциональную загрузку в базу по несколько тысяч элементов за 1 раз.

Comment: @MikeKharkov Получилось? Или еще надо пошаманить?

Comment: да в принципе можно ограничиться действительно поелементной загрузкой документов - скорость парсинга не сильно падает при этом. Просто если бы стояла принципиально задача грузить порционально как я описал и иметь такую структуру как выше требуется - тогда были бы серьезные проблемы у меня )

Comment: @MikeKharkov Можно разбить это всё к примеру через обычный for обходить рекурсивно, по 3-5К т.е. после await bulk.execute();  делать  client.close(); и снова вызывать функцию передавая значения индекса начала и конца цикла.. Но в целом Bulk() операции в mongosh и сопоставимые методы в драйверах не имеют ограничения на количество операций в группе. `При неупорядоченной массовой операции порядок операций в списке **может быть изменен для повышения производительности.**` Думаю под капотом Bulk() порционно отправляет по своим алгоритмам.

Comment: я тоже думаю что порционно иначе бы была куда более значительная разница в скорости отработки персинга между поелементной вставкой и целиком.
(и была бы не 10 процентов а 100 и выше.)